# validar petición php

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo dudas respecto a como validar que un valor que recibo vía GET con PHP, sean 4 números de un digito y positivo. Con strlen controlo la longitud pero como podría hacer para también controlar que sean positivos?

index.PHP:

```
<?php
 $combi = $_GET['combinacion']; //Contiene: 1234
 $valido = "Son 4 digitos positivos";
 $novalido="No son 4 digitos o no son positivos";


 if(strlen($combi) == 4){//SOLO ESTOY VALIDANDO LONGITUD, TAMBIEN DEBO VALIDAR SI SON POSITIVOS

echo '{"resp":"'.$afirmativo.'"}';
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres validar que sean 4 dígitos **positivos** debes considerar que un número negativo contiene el signo `-` por lo que una cadena con un número negativo sería algo como: `-1234`, su longitud ya es mayor que 4, entonces desde ese aquí ya puedes descartar que se una cadena válida.

Así que el código es simple, aunque tomando en cuenta la observación que te hice, el casteo de `$numero` a entero está demás, podrías lograrlo con una regex (para validar que solo sean números), pero para mantener el código sencillo dejaré el casteo y la validación.

```php
// $combi = $_GET['combinacion']; //Contiene: 1234
$combi = "1234";

function validar($str) {
    $valido = "Son 4 digitos positivos";
    $novalido = "No son 4 digitos o no son positivos";
    if (strlen($str) == 4) {
        foreach(str_split($str) as $numero) {
            if ((int)$numero < 0) return json_encode(array("resp" => $novalido));
        }
        return json_encode(array("resp" => $valido));
    }
    return json_encode(array("resp" => $novalido));
}

echo validar($combi);
# {"resp":"Son 4 digitos positivos"}
echo validar("123");
# {"resp":"No son 4 digitos o no son positivos"}
echo validar("1023");
# {"resp":"Son 4 digitos positivos"}
echo validar("1abc");
# {"resp":"No son 4 digitos o no son positivos"}
```